# How to change the bootstrap path in chef node

Tags: chef-infra

I have facing disk space issue whenever am running the

```
knife bootstrap ....
```

command on my workstation. By using the knife bootstrap command am installing the "chef-client" from the specific local URL and installing into the destination node.

In the destination node actually my `/home` folder does not have  sufficient space and also I can't expand this `/home`.

so can anyone guide me, how can I redirect the bootstrap default path to some other path(`/etc`, `/tmp`)in node.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of way to achieve it. I would go with a different destination as the install.sh script takes it as parameter. `knife bootstrap`has no option to set this extra arg but you can specify a fully new command.

Using the base one with a small addition this would give:

```
knife bootstrap --bootstrap-install-command "curl -L https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -d /tmp" [ rest of usual bootstrap options]
```

Another option is to create your own bootstrap template, [Documentation is here](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#custom-templates)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But hear my problem is that when am install the chef client through the boot strap command it will install on the node  predefined path on /home/dev path. but when we run the chef-client command on node once bootstrap process has been done again i will face the /home disk space issue. so Kindly advice to me how can i avoid the predefined path(/home) for chef client run on my node.

Comment: @Raja What is your full bootstrap command ? At first it should not use /home in any way so you must have something strange in your bootstrap template or some non standard options somewhere.

Comment: knife bootstrap SERVER_FQDN_or_IP --ssh-user SSH_USERNAME --ssh-password SSH_PASSWORD --node-name SERVER_FQDN --bootstrap-install-command "wget https://nexus.global.org/nexus/content/repositories/chef_repo/Linux/chef-client/12.9.38-1.el5.x86_64/chef-client-12.9.38-1.el5.x86_64.rpm;yum install -y chef-client-12.9.38-1.el5.x86_64.rpm" --sudo --use-sudo-password SSH_PASSWORD.

Comment: So you're using a custom command, that's up to you to use the proper wet parameters for the download and to switch directory. All in all, know what you're doing.

Comment: And as you're using a custom repo, I can't tell what is in the package you're downloading. Without precise informations there's no way to help you as it's not reproducible.

Comment: wget https://nexus.global.org/nexus/content/repositories/chef_repo/Linux/chef-client/12.9.38-1.el5.x86_64/chef-client-12.9.38-1.el5.x86_64.rpm

Comment: am trying to download the chef-client package from the above URL

Comment: Ok but why not from chef official repos ?

Comment: Accordingly In my organistion rules, we don't have access to official chef repos. so instead  of they have uploaded particular version in local repo.

Comment: Well it's a public Internet facing repo, with a bad ssl certificate (name not matching). So I can't tell if this package is an official one and how it behave